# Python: Pandas use slice with .describe() versions greater than 0.20

Tags: python, pandas, slice

Using this because its convenient.

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/aflaxman/436cde71f85b93638959

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,0,0,0,1,1],
                   'B': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'C': [8,9,10,11,12,13]})
```

[image: This use to work!]

This use to work!

Now:

```
>>> pandas.__version__
u'0.20.3'

df.groupby('A').describe().unstack()\
    .loc[:,(slice(None),['count','mean']),]
```

Gives:

```
TypeError: '['count', 'mean']' is an invalid key
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For columns remove `unstack`, because in version 0.20.0 was changed [groupby describe formatting](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#groupby-describe-formatting):

```
df = df.groupby('A').describe().loc[:,(slice(None),['count','mean'])]
print (df)

      B          C      
  count mean count  mean
A                       
0   4.0  2.5   4.0   9.5
1   2.0  5.5   2.0  12.5
```

---

MultiIndex is in `index`, so first `:` is removed, because select all index values.

Also there was added `slice(None)`, because `MultiIndex` has `3 levels`:

```
df = df.groupby('A').describe().unstack()\
    .loc[(slice(None),['count','mean'],slice(None))]

print (df)

          A
B  count  0     4.0
          1     2.0
   mean   0     2.5
          1     5.5
C  count  0     4.0
          1     2.0
   mean   0     9.5
          1    12.5
dtype: float64
```

Alternative solutions:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df = df.groupby('A').describe().unstack()\
    .loc[idx[:,['count','mean'],:]]

print (df)
          A
B  count  0     4.0
          1     2.0
   mean   0     2.5
          1     5.5
C  count  0     4.0
          1     2.0
   mean   0     9.5
          1    12.5
dtype: float64
```

---

```
df = df.groupby('A').describe().unstack()\
    .loc(axis=0)[:,['count','mean'],:]

print (df)
          A
B  count  0     4.0
          1     2.0
   mean   0     2.5
          1     5.5
C  count  0     4.0
          1     2.0
   mean   0     9.5
          1    12.5
dtype: float64
```

More information in [pandas documentation - using slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) .

Comment: Yeah, it was the unstack, that has changed the behavior.

Comment: Yes, exactly. unstack reshape dataframe and create MultiIndex in index.

Comment: and API was changed - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#groupby-describe-formatting, so is not necessary use `unstack`.

Comment: Sure, give me a sec.